# Member "sub" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in tuple()

Tags: types, solidity

I'm trying to convert a function to solidity 0.8.0 but keep getting a type error any help hold be appreciated

**TypeError: Member "sub" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in tuple().**

```
 function createViper(
    uint256 matron,
    uint256 sire,
    address viperOwner
)
    internal
    returns (uint)
{
    require(viperOwner != address(0));
    uint8 newGenes = generateViperGenes(matron, sire);
    Viper memory newViper = Viper({
        genes: newGenes,
        matronId: matron,
        sireId: sire
    });
    uint256 newViperId = vipers.push(newViper).sub(1);
    super._mint(viperOwner, newViperId);
    emit Birth(
        viperOwner,
        newViperId,
        newViper.matronId,
        newViper.sireId,
        newViper.genes
    );
    return newViperId;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.sub()` in this context is almost certainly a function of the [SafeMath](https://github.com/ConsenSysMesh/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol#L35) library.

In Solidity 0.8+ you don't need to use SafeMath anymore, because the integer underflow/overflow check is performed on a lower level.

So you can safely replace

```
uint256 newViperId = vipers.push(newViper).sub(1);
```

with

```
vipers.push(newViper);
uint256 newViperId = vipers.length - 1;
```

Comment: hi, i have tried this but get 2 errors - TypeError: Operator - not compatible with types tuple() and int_const 1 AND TypeError: Different number of components on the left hand side (1) than on the right hand side (0)

Comment: @konnection I see now that `push()` doesn't return the value in newer versions, my mistake. Updated the answer so it reflects this fact.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you are dealing with potentially larger numbers with less certain values, and you actually should take advantage of the SafeMath checks,
you can import it directly:

```
import './libraries/SafeMath.sol';  // check correct path
...
uint256 newViperId = SafeMath.sub(vipers.length, 1);
...
```